# HQL to insert entity references by passing property values?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I'm having problems sorting through all the Google results for my search terms; too much information that is *close* but not what I'm looking for, so... off to StackOverflow!

I have three tables, `Stocks`, `StockProperties`, and `StockPropertyTypes`.

One `Stock` record has zero or more `StockProperties` associated with it, and has a unique column `symbol`.  Each `StockProperty` record has exactly one reference to a `StockPropertyType`, and exactly one reference to a `Stock`.  The `StockPropertyTypes` table has a unique column `code`.  The entities for these tables do not have the FK id's for the references, just the classes.  For example, the `StockProperty` entity looks like:

```
public class StockProperty
{
    public virtual Guid StockPropertyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }

    public virtual string PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public virtual StockPropertyType Type { get; set; }
}
```

I want to pass into a method a stock symbol, a type code, and a value, and create a `StockProperty` record using HQL, but I'm not sure how to write that query.  The `Stocks` table and the `StockPropertyTypes` have no relation.  Seems like this should be some nested HQL query, but I'm not sure how to differentiate between a property and a referenced entity.

Can someone educate me what that HQL query should look like?

I should add, my goal here is to do this with one db trip; I don't want to load the `Stock` and `StockPropertyType` entities before creating the `StockProperty` record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to load the `Stock` and `StockPropertyType` from the `ISession`.  Then create a `StockProperty` to save using `ISession.Save()`.

As you mention, this requires a few extra trips to the DB.  One way to avoid this is to execute SQL directly as follows:

```
session
    .CreateSQLQuery(@"insert
                      into StockProperty(StockSymbol, Value, TypeCode)
                      values (:stockSymbol, :value, :typeCode)")
    .SetProperty("stockSymbol", stockSymbol)
    .SetProperty("value", value)
    .SetProperty("typeCode", typeCode)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

You are kind of bypassing NHibernate here, but it is more efficient.

Personally, I would consider loading the related entities into memory unless you are experiencing a bottleneck.  You can load both the `Stock` and `StockPropertyType` in a single DB call by using the `Future<T>()` paradigm.

***Alternatively...***

You could try fiddling with `<sql-insert>` inside of your hibernate mapping file.  This allows you more control over how the insert is generated.  You might want to add some properties `StockId` and `StockPropertyTypeId` that are only used during `insert`.

Comment: Ultimately, I did end up bypassing NHibernate.  Thanks.